# output from linux pipe in two inpdendent files

Tags: linux, pipe, standards

How do I pipe standard output from linux pipe in two inpdendent files?

I use a tool called openRTSP and which to standard output in two independent files
i.e. openRTSP > /tmp/file1 > /tmp/file2

Answer (score 8):

The command is `tee`. Its name is explicit.

```
openRTSP | tee /tmp/file1 > /tmp/file2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
openRTSP | tee /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```